# Send "iframe.contents()" to PHP Script through Ajax any ideas ?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, json

In my code I have an iFrame which loads dynamic content it's like a webpage(B.html) inside a page(A.php). in "A.php" user can edit inline the "B.html" once the process of editing has completed. In my submission I am sending iframes information to another page (script.php). I tried everything but content is not comming up in "script.php".

In nutshell, I want to tranfer my big html text with all stuff to a PHP via AJAX. I have no idea how to do it... my code would be something like below :-

Code for "A.php" inscript :
"myframe" is the iframe which contains the big chunk of HTML.

```
sendString = $("#myframe").contents();//Tried everything here[JSON as well] 
 $.ajax({
    url: "script.php",
    type: "POST",       
    data: sendingString,    
    cache: false,
    success: function (html) { 

         return html;
    } 
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,
Amjad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("#myframe").contents()` will get you it's nodes as a jQuery object. Try `$("#myframe").html()` instead to get the contents as a string.

**EDIT:** Oh, and it also helps if you fix your variable names. Change `data: sendingString` to `data: sendString`.

Comment: I'm not in a place where I can test right now but I don't think you can get an iFrame's contents with JavaScript of any type. Browsers specifically don't allow that to prevent a variety of hacks.

Comment: You are partially correct, but iFrame contents from the same origin *can* be accessed. That's what javascript WYSIWYG editors do. More info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: Ahh yes. I assumed a different origin because if it's same origin there's no reason to use iframes, IMHO. He could just include the files (or something similar) and wrap the whole thing with a div tag with an id. That would be a lot easier to play with than *shudder* iframes ;)

Comment: Finally I sent "HTML" data separate along with form data and that helped alot to improve the speed